# Append a radio button in list item after ajax call by using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, append, radiobuttonlist, ajaxform

I have jQuery code which creates variables and sends them to a PHP file by using AJAX. From the response I want to create a row of several list items that would be appended to their parents.

Everything works fine but the problem is that in this list items there is a radio button that every time will be appended in the first column of the row, like the other data, but when I want to toggle them all of the radios would be remain checked and the siblings of the selected one does not get unchecked.

I have tried to find the index of each radio button. I always get the index value of `0`. The radios have the same class name, so when I check the length of them I get the actual value, more than 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var add = '#submit';

  $(document).off().on('click', add, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var v1 = $('#value1').val();
    var v2 = $('#value2').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "addsettings.php",
      data: {
        v1: v1,
        v2: v2
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.includes("error")) {
          $('#message').html(data);
        } else {
          var result = $.parseJSON(data);
          var radio = result['radio'];
          var value = result['value'];

          var radiocheck = '<li><input type="radio" class="radiocheck" value="' + radio + '" /></li>';
          var insertvalue = '<li><div></div></li>';
          $('.result> .radiocheck').append(radiocheck);
          $('.result> .value').append(insertvalue);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id=submit></button>
<input type="text" id="value1" />
<input type="text" id="value2" />
<div class="result">
  <ul class="radiocheck"></ul>
  <ul class="value"></ul>
</div>
```

In the picture it is clear that both radio buttons are clicked and checked and they're not toggled.

[image]

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped by their name. Your radio buttons don't have a name.

Comment: So you mean I set name attribute for them with same name?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Each group that should be exclusive should have a unique name.

Comment: So by this setting the name and make them group, will I be able able to get each radio index value?

Comment: Why do you need the index value? Sure you can get that if you need, but it makes far more sense to get the value of the checked radio: `$('.radiocheck:checked').val()`

Comment: The reason of the getting index is to enable or disable some elements in the same row with equal index value.

Comment: In which case get the selected element and traverse the DOM from there using `next()`, `prev()`, `closest()`, `find()` etc.

Comment: Dear Roy, many appreciate for your concerns and help. Could you please send me any details or link regarding find() or else?